# An error when installing MPFR (3.1.0)

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, gmp, mpfr

I am trying to install MPFR (3.1.0) with the instructions from [this link](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~rks/mtp/installing_apron.txt)
 (part 3) and I get the following error:

> checking for gmp internal files... configure: error: header files
>   gmp-impl.h and longlong.h not found

I have already installed gmp (5.0.5) using the same page of instructions and it looked like the installation of gmp was successful.

Can someone please help me understand what the problem is, or suggest a work-around ?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
**Edit:** I get the error after I do

> ./configure --with-gmp-build=GMPBUILD # GMPBUILD=/usr/gmp/gmp-5.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Does the directory structure for GMP look like?

```
/usr/gmp/include
```

or

```
/usr/gmp/gmp-5.0.5/include
```

Once you verify the proper parent directory (/usr/gmp or /usr/gmp/gmp-5.0.5), try the following command:

```
./configure --with-gmp=GMPBUILD
```

where GMPBUILD is the parent directory of the include sub-directory.